# pure CSS non sass, hover over one element and expand the others

Tags: css, css-transitions

Using pure CSS. Without SASS. I'm wondering if it's possible to write something that allows a hover effect (different element to expand slightly in size) when hovered over a different element.

So basically. Hovering over one element, would expand a different div element that is neither a child or parent. Could I do this with pure CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS does not yet support any parent selector, so that's out of scope anyway. Besides children selectors (which you excluded) there are the two sibling selectors `+` for adjacent siblings and `~` for siblings in general.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: 1s all;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

div#one:hover + div#two {
  width: 200px;
}

div#one:hover ~ div#three {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">Hover me!</div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Note: Sibling selectors only work in order of appearance in code. So, `div#two ~ div#one` would *not* affect the first `div`.

Comment: +1. I was about to write the same thing. Note to the op: Elements that match the left side of the `+` and `~` combinators must precede the matches from the right side in the HTML.

Comment: Aaand you've worded that in plain English. Even better!

Comment: Was just about to write: thank you for the comment, I added a note about that. ;)